# Convert each parameter to question mark for query statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, parsing

I mean from this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tab WHERE col1 = 'name1' AND col2 in(1,2,3);
```

how to get this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tab WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 in(?,?,?);
```

`pg_stat_statements` does similar but it not saves original(with parameters) statement. I need original query also.

May be there is some open source or regex expression, which does this?

Comment: "Literal" I believe is the correct word you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Python, you may try:

```py
sql = "SELECT * FROM my_tab WHERE col1 = 'name1' AND col2 IN (1,2,3);"
output = re.sub(r'\bIN\s*\((.*?)\)', lambda m: 'IN (' + re.sub(r'\w+', '?', m.group(1)) + ')', sql)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tab WHERE col1 = 'name1' AND col2 IN (?,?,?);
```

Comment: Thanks but Python is not suitable. Its preferable if there is regex which can be used directly in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this for specific queries, but a general solution for this question would require parsing the SQL statement, which is complicated, to say the least.

Try to find a different solution for the problem underlying your question.